# Des fruits enivrant(s) (le palais) de douceurs et de bien-être

Tags: grammaire, orthographe, accord

> 1) - Des fruits enivrants.
>
> 2) - Des fruits enivrant le palais.
>
> 3) - Des fruits enivrant le palais de douceurs et de bien-être.
>
> 4) - Des fruits enivrants de douceurs et de bien-être.
>
> 5) - Des fruits enivrant de douceurs et de bien-être.

Les phrases quatre et cinq peuvent-elles être grammaticalement correctes, avec des nuances de sens ou y en a-t-il une des deux qui est à bannir, sans appel possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Le seul vrai problème que je remarque est l'orthographe du mot "bien-être".
Depuis une réforme relativement récente, la graphie "**bienêtre**" est recommandée. L'ancienne graphie "**bien-être**" est toujours acceptable mais pas "**bien être**".

Cela mis à part les phrases me semblent grammaticalement correctes.

La phrase 4 fait très lyrique et ne serait pas à utiliser dans un autre contexte.

La phrase 5 est un peu bancale, on y dit que les fruits "enivrent" quelque chose sans préciser quoi. Par contre:

> Des fruits enivrant de douceurs et de bien-être le palais.

Serait plus juste au niveau du sens, mais on y perd l'alexandrin (qui était peut-être recherché)

Comment: Si je suis d’accord avec les principes des règles orthographiques de 1990, mon œil reste sensible au `-` oublié... pourtant apprit il y a bien longtemps :) –  C’est exactement l’analyse que je souhaitais. En effet c’est la prosodie de l’alexandrin (pas la rime) qui est recherchée pour une lecture publique. La 5e proposition est vraiment bancale si on remplace palais par fleurs ! – P.S. : Je n’ai pas trouvé trois syllabes (finissant en *[v]rant*, ou *être)* à ajouter à votre dernière proposition pour en faire un haïku…

Answer (score 1):

Ces cinq phrases sont grammaticalement correctes. La 4 est celle qui sonne le mieux, cependant je l'aurais écrit ainsi :

> Des fruits enivrants de douceur et de bien-être

(en enlevant le s à douceur, donc)

« Douceur », ici, n'est pas quantifiable : on dit « de la douceur » et non pas - du moins pas dans ce contexte - « une douceur ». Autrement dit, les fruits t'apportent *de la douceur* et non pas *une douceur*.

Puisqu'on ne met pas de s à « bien-être » dans cette phrase, la même logique s'applique à « douceur ».

Answer (score 0):

(4) is preferable to (5). In (1) and (4) enivrant is an adjective and should bear the agreement of the plural. In (2) and (3) enivrant is the present participle of enivrer, the transitive verb, and therefore does not wear the mark of the plural. It's the presence of "le palais" (the verb's object) that makes it so.

Comment: I'd say 5 is also correct, as in "des fruits qui enivrent", using the present participle like in 2 and 3.

Comment: I agree it's not grammatically incorrect, but sounds contrived and unlikely to me